# Pipeline progress report

Tags: shell, pipe, progress-information

Suppose I'm running a pipeline like this:

```
cat input.txt | foo | bar | baz | last_step > result.txt
```

Is there a way to make the shell print each step to stderr as it is executed?

I know that if the commands `foo`, `bar` etc themselves printed to stderr it would accomplish this. However I'd like to have a general solution that does not rely on the pipeline steps providing progress info.

Comment: All the steps are executed concurrently, started at the same time. You could measure the rate of _data_ between two stages with something like `pv`, but I find it difficult to imagine what you're _actually_ looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I could find was something like this:

```
cat input.txt \
    | foo | pv -N "foo" \
    | bar | pv -N "bar" \
    | baz | pv -N "baz" \
    | last_step | pv -N "last_step" > result.txt
```

But I'm not sure if there's a better way.

Comment: I think I'd prefer saying it can't (or shouldn't) be done rather than suggest this solution. :)